# Basic deadlock issue, one mutex in multiple functions

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

I'm writing a program in C and which has 3 functions in it, A, B and C. I have a static mutex as global which is locking access to these functions. The functions A, B and C and be called in any order from multithreads so, my code looks as follows:

```
static pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int A() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    ... do some processing...
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    return anInt;
}

int B() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    ... do some processing...
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    return anInt;
}

int C() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    ... do some processing...
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    return anInt;
}
```

What might be causing the deadlock?

Comment: Can you post more code? What is there looks correct, apart from missing return statements.

Comment: Are there any paths through your code that exit a function before `pthread_mutex_unlock` is called?  Or does one of your functions call one of the others inside a lock?

Comment: @simonc No, A, B and C are called in order but by different threads so the might be called out of order

Comment: Another possibilities is that something (not shown) is writing over the memory of `mutex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is clean.

There are two possibilities to deadlock, if we skip rare cases with memory violations, etc:

1. Calling any of A(), B() or C() from the "locked" part of any one of these functions.
2. Returning from the "locked" part of any of these functions without pthread_mutex_unlock().

Both cases will cause deadlock because of double call of pthread_mutex_lock() on the same mutex.

Sorry if my English is bad :)

Comment: Your English is good, thank you for the response. Those are 2 possibilities I considered myself but in reviewing my code I didn't see how they might come about so I was curious if there was a third possibility. I'll have to take a closer look at my code.